# building 2 way table with angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to generate table that look like this https://output.jsbin.com/nowacafacu

But I'm stuck at here http://jsfiddle.net/ez2e12e4/

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="student in students">
    <div><i>{{student.name}}</i></div>
    <div>Grade:</div>
    <div>Mark:</div>
    <br>
    <div ng-repeat="data in student.data">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Tried for hours, need help from someone who's good in angularjs

Comment: unable to reach this site https://output.jsbin.com/nowacafacu
Please add screen shot how you need the output format

Comment: @Aravinder it's working for everyone else I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following  in your html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div id="header-row">
    <div class="date-header" ng-repeat="date in dates">
      {{date}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="table-row" ng-repeat="student in students">
    <div><i>{{student.name}}</i></div>
    <span>Grade:</span> 
    <span ng-repeat="x in student.data">
         {{x.grade}}
    </span>
    <br/>
    <span>Mark:</span> 
    <span ng-repeat="x in student.data">
         {{x.mark}}
    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to format it to proper table

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div id="header-row">
    <div class="date-header" ng-repeat="date in dates">
      {{date}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <table class="table-row" ng-repeat="student in students">
  <tr><td><i>{{student.name}}</i></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Grade:</td> 
    <td ng-repeat="x in student.data">
         {{x.grade}}
    </td>
    <tr>
    <td>Mark:</td> 
    <td ng-repeat="x in student.data">
         {{x.mark}}
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: the date have to be within the table.

Comment: just add another row = <tr><td>{{x.date}}</td</tr> below student name. Is it clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Nately

http://jsfiddle.net/sharmi1308/ez2e12e4/2/

```
                <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
              <div id="header-row">
                <div class="date-header" ng-repeat="date in dates">
                  {{date}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="table-row" ng-repeat="student in students">
                <div><i>{{student.name}}</i></div>
                <div class="gradewrap">
                  <div class="gradedetails">
                    <div>Grade:</div>
                    <div>Mark:</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="gradevalueswrap">
                    <div class="gradevalues" ng-repeat="data in student.data">
                      <div>
                        {{data.grade}}
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        {{data.mark}}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Nately im not sure i can bring it using <table>. Hope this will be better than table :). If table is ur requirement. Will try to work on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<div class="table-row" ng-repeat="student in students">
    <div><i>{{student.name}}</i></div>
    <span>
    Grade:
    </span>
    <span ng-repeat="data in student.data">
      {{data.grade}}
    </span>
    <br>
    <span>
    Marks:
    </span>
    <span ng-repeat="data in student.data">
      {{data.mark}}
    </span>
    <br>
  </div>
```

All the best.

Comment: nah this won't work mate, dates is an array, you don't hardcoded it like that.

Comment: This will not work If one student has multiple(n number of) grades

Comment: You can use `css` to transform .

Answer (score 0):

try following HTML sengment,

```
  <div class="table-row" ng-repeat="student in students">

    <div><i>{{student.name}}</i></div>

    <div>Grade:
      <div style="display:inline-block;padding: 10px;" ng-repeat="aGrade in student.data">
      {{aGrade.grade}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div >Mark:
       <div style="display:inline-block;padding: 10px;" ng-repeat="aGrade in student.data">
       {{aGrade.mark}}
       </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```